# SP 2013 Video Assets - Show author

Tags: custom, spservices, video

The 2013 video assets library has been a great blessing so far compared to 2010. 
However, there are still many pieces of data that would be nice to show in the thumbnail view.

Is there a way to the Author/custom-fields?
I take it that this is no OOTB, and I'll have to go into SP-Designer, or do something crazy with SPServices.

*Basically, the ask from a manager was if I can replicate the TED UI in SP...